# z-index - logo is going behind header

Tags: html, css

I am making a website however my logo is going behind the header even though the z-index is set higher. I do not know why? I have set a positioning so why is it not working? The overlays are both transparent .png s as I wanted to make it compatible with all browsers and RGBa is not.

[image: Photo of the problem]

The css is:

```
@charset "utf-8";

body {
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right:0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    padding:0px;
    z-index:-101;
}

#wrapper{
    margin-left:17.3875%;
}

#BG {
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: -100;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: 1040px;
}
/*HEADER*/
/*===================================================================*/
#header{
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    z-index:-98;
    position:fixed;
    z-index:-99;
    width:65.225%;
    height:18.2022472%;
    background:url(WireFrame/Nav%20Bar.png)
}

.logocontainer{
    width:34.1510157%;
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    z-index:-1;
    position:absolute;
    }

.logoimage{
    max-height:100%;
    max-width:100%;
    z-index:1;
    position:absolute;
}

#navigation{

}
/*BODY*/
/*===================================================================*/
#bodyoverlay{
    background:url(WireFrame/Body.png);
    position:fixed;
    z-index:-99;
    height:100%;
    width:65.225%;
    background-repeat:repeat-y
}

#body{
    z-index:-98;
    height:100%;
    width: 100%;

}
```

The html is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Home</title>
<link href="CSS.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
<img src="file:///U|/Year 8/ICT/Webdesign/WireFrame/Background.jpg" name="BG" width="4000" height="2670" id="BG" />
<div id = "wrapper">
    <header>
    <div id = "header">
        <div class="logocontainer">
        <img src="WireFrame/Logo.png" class="logoimage" />        </div>
        <nav>
            <div id = "navigation">         </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
    </header>
    <!---->
    <div id = "body">
        <div id = "bodyoverlay">
        </div>
        <div id = "Content">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of things wrong with the way you are using the `z-index` property:

- Firstly, you have to define a `position` for each element that has a `z-index`.
- Secondly, `z-index` does not order everything in a page absolutely -- there are different stacking contexts.
- (You also have multiple `z-index`es in the `#header`)

Here's [an excellent article on z-index that everyone should read](http://philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index/) and that should hopefully help you clear up the issues in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Items that are part of the layout should be CSS backgrounds, not inline images. It makes all of these issues suddenly go away.

Comment: what bit do you mean?

Comment: The Logo etc. If it is not content (part of the interface) it should be a background image, not an inline image. That way you don't have to play all kinds of positioning games.

Comment: @Diodeus I agree with the backgrounds being part of the CSS, but the logo is usually a link to the home page so it makes sense to me to keep that as page content

Comment: The image should be a background image of the A-tag in that case.

Comment: For some reason it never occurs to me to put backgrounds on links